# Why does canvas id not need a reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was reviewing some code and thought I had found an error in relation to a missing getElementById in the JavaScript code. However, the output appeared to be in order. Working backwards I found this

With HTML code as follows;

```
<canvas id="display" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<div id="stage" width="100" height="200"> </div>
<canvas id="hud" width="200"> </canvas>
```

..and JavaScript as below;

```
console.log(display.width); // displays 600
console.log(stage.width); // displays undefined as expected
console.log(hud.width); // displays 200
```

Any Id against the canvas element seems to need no formal declaration for the JavaScript to be able to find it within the HTML.

Am I missing something well known here? I note even on W3Schools that there is usually a variable declared to refer to the element ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

DOM elements with IDs are automatically accessible similarly to global variables.

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/2862621

Comment: Just to add to Tom's answer, the reason the div returns a width of `undefined` is because `width` is not a property of div. You don't define the width of a div like that. But in a canvas element you do define the property by adding `width="200"` in the HTML tag.

Comment: OK, many thanks for the answers. I wasn't quite sure what to search against. All of the above is useful